# php7-pecl-mongodb missing in alpine 3.10

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, alpine-linux

Recently upgraded to alpine 3.10 (docker image) because I need php 7.3 for given security fix.

During build I install php7-pecl-mongodb. Seems like this package is no longer available in 3.10.

Get the following error during build:

```
  php7-pecl-mongodb (missing):
  ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  required by: world[php7-pecl-mongodb]
```

Cannot find package in alpine library and when searching the web I can read that the package is not available in alpine 3.10.

What is the replacement for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working version 1.6.1-r0 of php7-pecl-mongodb in the edge testing repository:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ php7-pecl-mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [edge](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=php7-pecl-mongodb&branch=edge) or [v3.9](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=php7-pecl-mongodb&branch=v3.9), as it does not exist in v3.10.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/ php7-pecl-mongodb=1.5.3-r2
```

Comment: This version did install, but gave me later problems with composer. Found working version in edge testing.